# Drawing shapes in loops

Tags: java, swing

So Im basically just trying to Draw a whole bunch of random triangles to the screen in a loop while changing the colors which seemed not very difficult but i cannot find where my problem lies... it wont loop it just displays one image here's what i have

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ManyTriangles extends Canvas {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int x1 = r.nextInt(350);
        int x2 = r.nextInt(400);
        int x3 = r.nextInt(300);
        int y1 = r.nextInt(800);
        int y2 = r.nextInt(200);
        int y3 = r.nextInt(600);
        int[] xpts = { x1, x2, x3 };
        int[] ypts = { y1, y2, y3 };

        int randomColor = r.nextInt(3);
        for (int x = 0; x <= 500; x++) {
            if (randomColor == 3) {
                g.setColor(Color.green);
            } else if (randomColor == 2) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
            } else if (randomColor == 1) {
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
            }
            g.fillPolygon(xpts, ypts, 3);


        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ManyTriangles canvas = new ManyTriangles();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lots of Triangle's");

        frame.setSize(1024, 768);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your `xpts` and `yppts` never change within the loop, so you are painting the same thing over and over again in different colors
2. You've broken the paint chain by not calling `super.paint`
3. You're mixing heavy and light weight components (`Canvas` on a `JFrame`), this is not really a good idea...

## Instead...

1. Move the creation of the `xpts` and `yppts` into the `loop`
2. Call `super.paint` before doing any custom painting or event better
3. Use a `JPanel` instead of a `Canvas` and override it's `paintComponent` method instead, making sure you call `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting...

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

## Other issues...

- Because you're re-generating the output each time `paint` is called, your output could change at random times (as the repaint manager schedules new repaint requests).  If you don't want this, generate the shapes in the constructor or other method, adding them to some kind of `List` or array and iterate over  this within your `paintComponent` method...